# About inconsistency of first order set theories?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, incompleteness

If we have a first order set theory $T$, i.e. its language is first order logic with the membership symbol added as the sole extra-logical primitive. Supposed that $T$ proves the existence of a set $\mathcal M$ and a set $\mathcal E$ of ordered pairs in $\mathcal M$: such that if we replace each atomic formula $x \in y$  by $[\exists p \in \mathcal E (\text{ordered-pair}(p,x,y))]$ and bound all quantifiers to $\mathcal M$, in all axioms of $T$, then $T$ proves that each replacing sentence is true, i.e. if $\alpha$ was an axiom of $T$ then $T$ proves that the replacement sentence $\alpha'$ of $\alpha$ to be true.

Of course the ternary relation "ordered-pair" is definable in $T$ and provable in it to satisfy the basic property of ordered pairs, also it satisfies the existence of Cartesian products between any two sets in terms of them, and domains, co-domains, and ranges of sets of them.

Suppose that $T$ meets conditions for Godels incompleteness arguments, through interpreting Robinson's arithmetic $\sf Q$ for example, and of course having a recursively enumerable set of theorems. Then does that ***always*** mean that $T$ proves the existence of a model of it, and thus it proves its own consistency and thus $T$ is inconsistent?

Comment: Hmm "$T$ meets the conditions for Gödel's incompleteness arguments" is rather fuzzy to work with, because it doesn't specify _how_ we should code up numbers in the theory. Up until that point in the question, a possible $T$ could have had extensionality and $\forall xy(x\notin y)$ as its only axioms.

Comment: Ok I've added the conditions of interpreting Robinson's arithmetic and being effectively axiomatized.

Comment: There's an ambiguity in "T proves all the replaced sentence to be true." It could mean that T proves the single statement "all the replaced sentences are true". Or it could mean that, for each axiom $\alpha$, T proves "the replaced version of $\alpha$ is true." Only with the former meaning would it follow that T proves its own consistency (and even then only if T proves a version of the soundness theorem, so that having a model implies consistency).

Comment: @AndreasBlass, so $T$ must have ability to express "$\alpha$ is a represented sentence" by a single formula. Its not enough to schematically prove every instance of that representation.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, does it matter if the total number of axioms of $T$ is finite?

Comment: If the number of axioms is finite, and if the definition of "axiom of T" used in the consistency statement and in the definition of "model of T" explicitly lists the axioms (rather than giving some complicated alternative characterization), and if T proves soundness (existence of a model implies consistency) in addition to the assumptions in your question, then yes, if T proves that it has a model, then T is inconsistent.